# PHP : Using a variable to hold a table name, and using that variable in queries

Tags: php, mysql, database, variables

I am currently learning PHP, and I'm working on a Registration Form.
Somewhere in my code I have these statements

```
$query = "SELECT `stud_no` FROM `tb_registered_users` WHERE `stud_no`='$studno'";
```

and

```
$query = "INSERT INTO `tb_registered_users`
VALUES ('".$studno."','".$firstname."','".$lastname."')";
```

but instead I want to declare this variable and use it in the queries mentioned above

```
$mysql_tb = 'tb_registered_users';
```

So what is the correct syntax for this?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
$query = "INSERT INTO `" . $mysql_tb . "`
VALUES ('".$studno."','".$firstname."','".$lastname."')";
```

Answer (score 10):

```
<?php
$mysql_tb = 'tb_registered_users';
$query = "SELECT `stud_no` FROM `{$mysql_tb}` WHERE `stud_no`='$studno'";
$query = "INSERT INTO `{$mysql_tb}` VALUES ('".$studno."','".$firstname."','".$lastname."')";
```

Comment: this curly bracket syntax changed my life, didn't know that was possible thank you!

Comment: @Yueyu could you please explain what is the work of curly bracket

Answer (score 1):

```
$mysql_tb = 'tb_registered_users';

$query = "SELECT `stud_no` FROM `".$mysql_tb."` WHERE `stud_no`='$studno'";
```

Answer (score 1):

You can just do it as

```
$query = "SELECT `stud_no` FROM " . $mysql_tb . " WHERE `stud_no`='$studno'";
```

but I would recommend looking into PDO ( http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php && http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/why-you-should-be-using-phps-pdo-for-database-access/).

Answer (score 1):

```
$query = "SELECT `stud_no` FROM `".$mysql_tb."` WHERE `stud_no`='$studno'";
```

and

```
$query = "INSERT INTO `".$mysql_tb."` VALUES ('".$studno."','".$firstname."','".$lastname."')";
```

You may also want to look into using something like [PDO](http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepare.php) which will allow you to use named parameters and avoid SQL injections.

Answer (score 1):

Also worked for me if using double quotes:

```
$newDataInput = "INSERT INTO $mysql_tb (Date,Time) VALUES ('$date','$time')";
```

Answer (score 1):

BTW you can also use sprintf function to do the same thing as show below

(PHP 4, PHP 5, PHP 7)
sprintf — Return a formatted string

```
$mysql_tb = 'tb_registered_users';
$query1 = sprintf("SELECT `stud_no` FROM `%s` WHERE `stud_no`='$studno'",$mysql_tb);
$query2 = sprintf("INSERT INTO `%s` VALUES ('".$studno."','".$firstname."','".$lastname."')",$mysql_tb);
```

Just put %s in place where you want to replace the value and then use second parameter as variable as shown in here. It works as same as function in c language and c++. You can replace multiple values also with multiple parameters. Here is php manual help

https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.sprintf.php
Hope that helps